# Resolution problems with Dell XPS 15 9550 but only in X11, in Wayland it's fine

Tags: drivers, nvidia, xorg, dell, display-resolution

I've been using Wayland for a while without many issues but I wanted to switch back to X11 to see if there's a noticeable difference in performance / stability. However, when I switch to X11 my laptop is stuck in an ultra low resolution (950 x 540, something like that) and I cannot get it out. I've tried switching from proprietary drivers to open source...removing the drivers, etc. but nothing works.

On Ubuntu 18.04, with a Dell XPS 15 9550. No setting available in the menu to increase the resolution to native 1080p in xorg.

Someone able to help?

Comment: Wayland now works with proprietary drivers? That's new to me.

Comment: I'm a Linux newb, Wayland works perfectly fine as is it *says* it's working with Nvidia drivers but that's not the concern here. Xorg is not working in my laptop's native resolution in 1080p.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I figured it out. I had to fix a dependency issue with my nvidia graphics driver, purge the nvidia drivers (and the xorg config, more importantly) and then revert to open source drivers. After an hour and a half of searching, I figured it out, I booted back into xorg, and finally, the resolution options updated to allow me to change to 1080p.

Back in business!